# python matplotlib: Update the random.normal series in histogram using TextBox widgets

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, series

I am trying to create an interactive histogram which displays a random.normal series. The interaction should allow for a TextBox widget to pass new values for the random.normal function and redraw the histogram. So far, I have an initial histogram showing with the input boxes, but I can't even make the boxes to accept input. I have tried recreating the histogram each time a value is input in the TextBox widget:

```
normal = np.random.normal

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-6,9.5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 0.25)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

nloc = 1.0
nscale = 2.0

a = plt.hist(normal(nloc, nscale, 1000), bins=30, alpha=0.5, density = True)

def submitloc(text):
    value = float(text)
    nseries = normal(value, nscale, 1000)
    plt.sca(ax)
    plt.cla()
    a = plt.hist(nseries, bins=30, alpha=0.5, density = True)
    plt.draw()

def submitscale(text):
    value = float(text)
    nseries = normal(nloc, value, 1000)
    plt.sca(ax)
    plt.cla()
    a = plt.hist(nseries, bins=30, alpha=0.5, density = True)
    plt.draw()

axbox = plt.axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05])
text_box = TextBox(axbox, 'loc ', initial=nloc)
text_box.on_submit(submitloc)

axbox2 = plt.axes([0.3, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05])
text_box2 = TextBox(axbox2, 'scale ', initial=nscale)
text_box2.on_submit(submitscale)

plt.show()
```

I have also tried changing the global variables nloc and nscale from the textbox input:

```
normal = np.random.normal

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-6,9.5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 0.25)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

nloc = 1.0
nscale = 2.0

def drawplot(nloc, nscale):
    plt.hist(normal(nloc, nscale, 1000), bins=30, alpha=0.5, density = True);
    plt.show()

def submitloc(text):
    plt.sca(ax)
    plt.cla()
    global nloc
    nloc = float(text)
    drawplot(nloc, nscale)

def submitscale(text):
    plt.sca(ax)
    plt.cla()
    global nscale
    nscale = float(text)
    drawplot(nloc, nscale)

drawplot(nloc, nscale)

axbox = plt.axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05])
text_box = TextBox(axbox, 'loc ', initial=nloc)
text_box.on_submit(submitloc)

axbox2 = plt.axes([0.3, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05])
text_box2 = TextBox(axbox2, 'scale ', initial=nscale)
text_box2.on_submit(submitscale)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `TextBox` shows text. This means the `initial` value must be a string.

```
TextBox(axbox, 'loc ', initial=str(nloc))
```

Comment: Thank you! Well, it was a simple tweak which had consumed me one week